# Is there an event that can catch changes in row data while user editing?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want something like [AngularJS 'watch' function](http://www.learn-angular.org/#!/lessons/watch).
While user edits a row, I want to fire an event. 
[In this example](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/Editing/access-editor-control) this event catches when user clicks on a row, but I want an event that can catch only when user changes data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [`edit`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-edit) event of the Grid, obtain reference to the edited data item (`e.model`) and [`bind`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/widget-basics/events-and-methods#event-binding-after-initialization) to its [`change`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/model#events-change) event.

```
edit: function(e) {
    e.model.bind("change", function(j) {
        // ...
    });
}
```

**UPDATE**

In case you want to update the data item or other content in the Grid, attach a `keyup` handler to the desired textbox or edit widget, then trigger `change`, so that the model updates. Optionally, use the `change` event of the model itself to modify other values or content on the page.

http://dojo.telerik.com/oKiyE

```js
        $(document).ready(function () {
          var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            pageSize: 20,
            data: products,
            schema: {
              model: {
                id: "ProductID",
                fields: {
                  ProductID: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                  ProductName: { validation: { required: true } },
                  UnitsInStock: { type: "number", validation: { required: true } }
                }
              }
            }
          });

          $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: dataSource,
            pageable: true,
            height: 550,
            toolbar: ["create"],
            columns: [
              { field: "ProductName", title: "Product Name" },
              { field: "UnitsInStock", title: "Units in Stock" },
              { title: "Product Name readonly", template: "<span id='Product#= ProductID#'>#= ProductName #</span>" },
              { command: "edit", title: " ", width: "150px" }],
            editable: "inline",
            edit: function(e) {
              var model = e.model;

              var input = e.container.find("[name=ProductName]");

              input.keyup(function(){
                input.trigger("change");
              });

              model.bind("change", function(j){
                if (j.field == "ProductName") {
                  model.set("UnitsInStock", model.get("UnitsInStock") + 1);
                  $("#Product" + model.get("ProductID")).html(model.get("ProductName"));
                }
              });
            }
          });
        });

        function readOnlyEditor(container, options) {
          container.html(options.model.get(options.field));
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <script src="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/content/shared/js/products.js"></script>

      <div id="grid"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i dont think that this is that i want. See this data-value-update example (http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/mvvm/elements) . Without user click anywhere else text model update immediately. I want this behaviour in my kendo grid on editable mode

Comment: I am not sure I understand what "without user click anywhere" means. The Model state is initially constructed as a result of a `kendo.bind()` call. Afterwards, the model state changes only when the `change` event of an `input` or a `select` is fired. The behavior in the Grid edit form is similar.

Comment: The example show two input.In first one, you change model but in rigth form you dont see any changes until another event fired. The second input has different behaviour, you can see changes in model immediately. Grid in editable mode has behaviour like the first input, i want to change it and act like second input

Comment: Thanks dude!! this is exactly that i want